# SSISDB 2019 Script Component is Blank

Tags: ssis

I have a SSIS package runs fine in visual studio but will not run deployed as a job in SSIDB.

The first error message was

> Data Flow Task:Error: The binary code for the script is not found.
> Please open the script in the designer by clicking Edit Script button
> and make sure it builds successfully.

Researching this pointed to an issue with the package version and SSISDB version.   I was deploying the job as 2017 on an SSIDB that was 2019.

I downloaded vs2019 and updated the package version to 2019.   Now I get an login failed error.

> RentalExchangeUpload:Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE
> DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E4D.  An OLE DB record is
> available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"
> Hresult: 0x80040E4D  Description: "Login failed for user domain\user.

The user and password are stored in the package parameters.   All other SSIS packages deployed as 2017 with the same connection string are running find from the SSISDB.

Not sure what else to try.

Comment: *domain\user* is a _windows_ user - this does not have a password in your SSIS package. Are you intending to connect via a windows login or via SQL authentication (which does have a password)

Comment: SQL authentication which the userid and password is stored in the connection string for the package parameters.

Comment: Your error indicates you are not using SQL Auth. You are using windows auth.

Comment: Went back and checked the connection strings for the connections.  One was still using windows authentication.  Changed it. Have to wait until Monday when job runs again to see if that was the problem.  Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do you get the second error message?

In Visual Studio 2019 or SQL Agent job?

1. If in Visual Studio 2019 , please check if the user and password are correct in the connection manager.
   Please try to create new connection manager.
2. If in SQL Agent job, it seems that the user *domain\user* does not have right permissions to access the information of ssis packages.
   Please [**create SQL Server Agent proxy**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-sql-server-agent-proxy?view=sql-server-ver15) to execute the ssis packages in job.

Comment: As mentioned above looks like I missed that one of the connections was using windows authentication instead SQL Server.  Thank You.